# passing parameters in form using laravel8 route

Tags: php, laravel-8

```
<form action="{{route('products.update',$products->id)}}" method="post">
```

this code make this error: **Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: Because `$products` is a collection of multiple products, not a single product. Are you attempting to update 1 product or all products?

Comment: I'm attempting to update 1 product but that's not the problem ,the same code with laravel 6 or 7 run without any problem only in 8 I faced that problem

Comment: If `$products` is a collection, how exactly can Laravel guess which one should get updated? I highly doubt this would "work" in any Laravel version whatsoever, as it doesn't make sense to begin with.

Comment: `$product->id` should be what's passed here, not `$products->id`. The former is a single product, the latter is a collection of multiple products.